# how can I preserve the digits following the decimal place in a money datatype?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

how can I preserve the digits following the decimal place in a money datatype?
the problem I have is every time I try to cast the data to a string, I lose precision...

for example:

I am trying to use a money datatype to store phone numbers (it seems like the most optimal storage size) EDIT: storage size is a major issue for me (8 bytes for money datatype instead of 16+ bytes for varchar field)

If I am storing 10 digits on the right side of the decimal place and 3-4 digits on the right of the decimal place as the extension, when I try to 'parse' the extension, I seem to lose anything more than 2 digits

so a phone number like this: (305) 444-1234 ext 283 would be stored in a money datatype like this: 3054441234.283

the problem I have is if I use a CAST(myMoneyValue as varchar(x)) then 3054441234.283 turns into 3054441234.28

can anyone help?

EDIT2: let's pretend for a moment I didn't mention storing a phone number in there... let's say there was a reason I needed to concatenate a money datatype together with a varchar field... e.g. If I wanted to concatenate '$' + 0.1125 + ' / sqft.' - is there any way to preserve the .0025 portion of the money field?

Comment: Your biggest problem is that you're trying to store a phone number in a `money` datatype. Don't do that.

Comment: How is this most optimal? Optimization does not involve *just* the bytes you lay down on disk. Think of all the converting, casting and validating you have to do when you move data in and out of this column.

Comment: Your problem statement indicates that you are storing all of the digits to the right of the decimal points: 10 and 3-4.

Comment: I was trying to simplify the problem statement with a single case... I would actually like to store more than just 10 digit + 4 digit extension, but as @gbn explained, I will encounter a problem with leading zeros on international phone numbers.

Comment: Anytime you find you are having to cast data to another data type to use it, then you have a database smell indicating a possible design issue.

Comment: Regarding EDIT2 - yes, don't convert to varchar using the default format.

Comment: Re: EDIT2: format in the client code, not SQL Server

Comment: Why the downvotes?  This seems like a legitimate question even if people are offended by SkyGuard trying to store a phone number as money.

Answer (score 9):

You store phone numbers in varchar fields, perhaps decomposed into country/area codes, extension number etc.

If you insist, then either:

- use [STR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) to format the value
- use [`CONVERT(varchar(20), MyMoneyColumn, 2)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

What about the leading zeroes used in many countries?

Comment: you can easily store a phone number as a numeric, but I agree it makes more sense to store as a varchar.

Comment: @Jeremy: "leading zeros" like most of Europe bollixes the use of a number. The zero is suppressed when dialing out of country. And international prefix is "+" because it might not be 00. It's varchar

Comment: @gbn good point about the leading zeros for international countries. Thanks for the helpful constructive criticism.

Comment: @gbn: strongly typing a 10 digit number was indicative of domestic.  Since we have already established that it's not a good idea to store the phone as numeric data, I submit that in all cases it is still possible, just a heck of a lot more work than it will ever be worth.  To date, nobody dials anything other than a digit to call someone.

Comment: @Jeremy, I can (and frequently do) dial `*67{phonenumber}` to call people.  `*` is not a digit.

Comment: it's not part of the phone number either.

Comment: @Jeremy: my profile say British, living in Switzerland. Define "domestic"

Comment: @Abe Miessler would you actually store a phone number in your "little black book" as *67{phonenumber}? (I am not familiar with how this is used - or what *67{phonenumber} does - I'm trying to learn about all phone number possibilities could be)

Comment: Yes I do store it in my phone with the *67

Comment: @Jeremy, it's part of the phone number that I just dialed.  My point was that your statement,  `To date, nobody dials anything other than a digit to call someone.` is not entirely true.

Comment: I will clarify then: To date, all phone numbers can in fact be represented purely by digits.  You do not *need* to dial anything other than digits, and there are no numbers that cannot be dialed if all you can dial are digits, with the exception of control codes the phone companies might use (like *67).  Therefore, any person's or organization's assigned phone number can be accurately represented by a numeric field with enough scale to support the entirety of the number.  But yeah, you would gain little storage space and lose a lot of time, aggravation, and infrastructure in doing so.

Answer (score 6):

Stop using the money datatype to store phone numbers.  If you want it as a varchar then store it as a varchar.  It doesn't make sense to store this as something else just to convert it later on.

It will also confuse others that look at your data later on (say after you are hit by a bus and leave no documentation behind).  Also, casting can cause problems with index usage and can really slow down your queries.

Comment: I was not specific enough - storage size is a very important issue, since I need to keep the footprint of the database file small. I am storing a phone number, so I'm not sure how a varchar is appropriate (I haven't seen any phonenumbers such as 123-sad-face).  To store a 10 digit phone number + 4 digit extension I would need 16 bytes per row... the money datatype only needs 8 bytes. I was able to solve this problem by isolating the right side and multiplying by 1000.

Comment: @Skyguard: that's a premature optimisation. How much processing does it take to multiply and CAST? An extra few bytes per row is most likely to be trivial because of how rows fit into pages

Comment: @Skyguard: How about 1-800-GOFEDEX or 1-800-PICK-UPS?

Comment: @gbn To be honest, I haven't calculated the performance difference. I wonder if anyone would have actually answered my question if I hadn't mentioned storing a phone number in there. No one really answered the question I posed about how to preserve the digits following the decimal place. It's too bad people seem more concerned with thumping their chests instead of actually answering a very specific and legitimate question (I'm not commenting on you specifically, just an observation).

Comment: @Skyguard The issue has never been not preserving the decimal places.  In money, everything is preserved.  It was your conversion to varchar which was using a default format.  And conversions are always expensive, regardless of why you are converting.  And conversions of millions of rows for things are also very expensive - and conversion of millions of rows to try to search for all phone numbers in a particular area code will also be expensive - something that is trivially fast with an index on a varchar column.

Comment: @skyguard: I gave you solutions *and* feedback. I work on systems with millions of inserts *per minute* and would use varchar

Comment: @gbn I wasn't criticizing you actually, you gave the most useful feedback to me in the entire thread.

Answer (score 4):

`CAST(myMoneyValue as varchar(x))` assumes two decimal places by default (converting money to varchar).  You can force it to whatever number of decimal places you want.

**BUT YOU CANNOT KNOW** if it's a 3 or 4 digit extension in advance (1234567.123 - is that 123-4567 x 123 or 123-4567 x 1230 - they are both the **same** in money/decimal's internal representations - unless you go to the trouble of always padding them on the left after the decimal - 1234567.0123 is 123-4567 x 123 - so now the money aren't even as human readable in their "native form").

I think this pretty much shows why you shouldn't use decimal or money for this data.

Comment: I found the solution was to multiply by 1000 (shift the decimal over) and then do my string operations. This solved my problem (I feel stupid, but hopefully this helps someone else)

Comment: @Skyguard: the word for that is "ugly hack", not solution

Comment: @gbn - I didn't mention at the beginning that the most primary issue I have is the storage size of the overall database needs to be as small as possible. This seems to be the best solution I can come up with so far (it solves the problem as far as my needs go - with the exception of international phone numbers with leading zeros - thanks for your point)

Comment: and I have seen extensions that were more than 4 digits

Comment: @Skyguard: Why is the size so important?

Comment: @Skyguard Why use money then, just use a decimal with no digits after the decimal - or a long int.

Comment: @Skyguard I thought you were just going to multiple all numbers by 1000.  You can encode just about anything in an int, if you have a long enough int.  We regularly code dates (and times) in ints in data warehouses - YYYYMMDD.  But that's not the point here.  The point is that for PHONE NUMBERS, using integer (or some fixed point) encoding is not a good idea.  And it's a false economy, because your conversions are going to eat cycles and your working set in queries is going to be larger, and NULL/empty/short varchars are actually going to save you space in the database compared to money.

Comment: @Cade Roux re: multiply by 1000, I meant I would isolate the right side (i.e. if 1234567.239 then I would isolate the '239' and multiply .239 by 1000) but after hearing everyone saying "don't do it!" (and "code is smelly" and "it's an ugly hack") I changed phonenumbers to varchar(15) as per what everyone was saying. The most convincing of all arguments for me to do this was actually gbn and the concept that international phone # with leading zeros won't work.

Comment: @Skyguard, I have a Polish number (Gdynia) bigger than 15 given as: "+48(0)58 621 99 99" - I have an Irish number (Dublin) also bigger than 15 given as: "+353 (0)16685999" - this is per those users' email signatures - may want to consider making it a little bigger if you aren't splitting off the country code/area code.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying really hard to complicate your task - simply store the phone number as **char** or **varchar** of appropriate length.

**Regarding EDIT2:**

The [`style` value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for `money` or `smallmoney` conversion to character data is:

- **0 (default)** - no commas every three digits to the left of the decimal point, and two digits to the right of the decimal point; for example, **4235.98**
- **1** - commas every three digits to the left of the decimal point, and two digits to the right of the decimal point; for example, **3,510.92**
- **2** - no commas every three digits to the left of the decimal point, and four digits to the right of the decimal point; for example, **4235.9819**

You need to use the last one:

```
CONVERT(varchar(x), myMoneyValue, 2)
```

Comment: varchar takes much more room to store the same data (it's purely numeric data) and I need to optimize storage size. Since there will be millions of rows in the table it would be expensive to store phone numbers with varchar/char

Comment: @Skyguard: Did you make any calculations to estimate how much space you can save for, let's say, every million of rows? What's the maximum size of the database suitable for your needs?

Comment: We have millions of rows in our system (millions of rows being a tiny database BTW) and store it as varchar or nvarchar. I know of no professional database designer who would consider storing phone numbers any other way - they are NOT numbers, they are string data by definition same as postal codes should never be stored as anything except varchar or nvarchar.

Answer (score 2):

Your biggest problem is that you're trying to store a phone number in a money datatype.  Don't do that, and then you won't have this problem.

A phone number is not a "number" in the traditional sense.  Leading zeros are significant, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

try casting as NUMERIC(14,4).  Money is not a good data type for this, for precisely the reasons you are seeing.

Comment: I tried this, but it loses all the digits (i.e. 3054441234.28 turns into 3054441234.0000)

Comment: It does what?  That doesn't make sense.  I think you're losing something in a conversion somewhere.  I think you're going to be much better off with gbn's answer than dealing with the headaches you're volunteering for.

Answer (score 1):

[Runnable example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/110188/http-msdn-microsoft-com-en-us-library-ms187928-aspx)

```
-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

DECLARE @money AS MONEY = 12345.6789

SELECT CONVERT(varchar, @money), CONVERT(varchar, @money, 2)
```